# Ag-Grid (React) - How to resize the row based on manul resize?

Tags: reactjs, resize, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

In my case want to resize the entire row of ag grid by dragging down

Tried flow :
As of now am tried with JQuery for manually calculate and update row height during manual resize

Expect to achieve this feature in ag-grid react itself